# How many times should I perform an experiment to get a high level of accuracy?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, mathematical-modeling, experimental-mathematics

I have an experiment with 4 factors (independent variables). The first and second variable have 8 levels, the third 5 and the fourth only 3 levels. Theres one dependent variable. How many times should I perform the experiment in order to get a high level of accuracy? For instance a 95%. I would appreciate the mathematical procedure behind this calculation. Thank you.

Comment: what is a level of a variable?

Comment: with level I meant the different states a factor can take i.e. one factor could be pressure with 3 levels: 10 psi, 20 psi and 30 psi

Comment: From finitely many experiments you do an estimate of yours parameters of interest, if that sequence of parameters clearly converges numerically, then you can assume there is a good reason for that and search for the assumptions implying the theoretical variance of those estimates decay fast enough.

Comment: Are you trying to estimate a population parameter?

Comment: No population. Im trying to model a physics phenomena with physical variables.

Comment: When you say “accuracy”, do you mean that you want the model to be accurate as measured by some quantity like the $R^2$?   Is the response stochastic, or deterministic?

Comment: An experiment is going to be performed as many times as I like, however, in order to save resorces and time, theres a precise number of experiemnts that allow me to get statistically significant data without doing lots of experiements. Thats my question, how to calculate that if I want to get a i.e. 95% of accuracy

Comment: Consider asking this on the stats stack exchange.